# Serialize custom data in DRF

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two types of static data and don't need any models because I don't want to save those data in the database. The data are generated from a class `RandomObjectGenerator`.

- Data 1 is a string whose length could be up to `2,097,152`
- Date 2 is a JSON data whose size could be up to 4 like `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}`

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .generate import RandomObjectGenerator
from .serializers import ObjectSerializers
import json
# Create your views here.

class ApiView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        randomObject=RandomObjectGenerator().get_random_objects()
        randomObjectCount=RandomObjectGenerator().get_random_object_count()
        objectSerialize=ObjectSerializers(data={'randData':randomObject,'randCount': json.dumps(randomObjectCount)})
        if objectSerialize.is_valid():
            objectSerialize.save()
            return Response(objectSerialize.data)
        else:
            return Response(objectSerialize.errors)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ObjectSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    randData=serializers.CharField()
    randCount=serializers.IntegerField()
```

I am getting two types of errors here. If I use `serializers.IntegerField()` then I am getting the  `"A valid integer is required."` error then if I try to use `serializers.CharField()` then it's showing `create() must be implemented.`

I got stuck for while and couldn't get any idea how i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`create()` need to be implemented on any serializer you call `.save()` because calling create is what save does.

So the question really is, why are you calling .save() if you have no intention of saving this to a database? what are you conceptually saving here?

Removing the row with save() from the view should solve your issue.